# Sending message on youtube live chat with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm trying to add a button that can send a message to the live chat but I don't think it's finding the proper input element.

I added some logs to try and find it.

```
const sendMessage = (message) => {
  console.log('Sending message:', message);
  const chatInputBox = document.querySelector('#input');
  console.log('Chat input box:', chatInputBox);
  chatInputBox.focus();
  chatInputBox.innerText = message;
  chatInputBox.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
  setTimeout(() => {
    const sendButton = document.querySelector('#button');
    console.log('Send button:', sendButton);
    if (sendButton) {
      console.log('Clicking send button');
      try {
        sendButton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', { bubbles: true }));
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error sending message:', error);
      }
    } else {
      console.error('Could not find send button');
    }
  }, 1000);
};
};
```

> content.js:42 Sending message: Hello!
> content.js:44 Chat input box: <g id=​"input">​<path d=​"M21 3.01H3c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2V9h2V4.99h18v14.03H3V15H1v4.01c0 1.1.9 1.98 2 1.98h18c1.1 0 2-.88 2-1.98v-14c0-1.11-.9-2-2-2zM11 16l4-4-4-4v3H1v2h10v3z">​​​
> content.js:50 Send button: <button id=​"button" class=​"style-scope yt-icon-button">​<yt-icon id=​"close-icon" icon=​"yt-icons:​close" class=​"style-scope ytd-miniplayer">​…​​flex​
> content.js:52 Clicking send button

Comment: I've managed to get the text input working with this change but the button doesn't click

`const sendMessage = (message) => {
  const liveChatFrame = document.querySelector('iframe.style-scope.ytd-live-chat-frame');
  const chatInputBox = liveChatFrame.contentDocument.querySelector('#input.yt-live-chat-text-input-field-renderer');`

Comment: Try document.execCommand, [example](/a/57900849).

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with contentDocument to find the input and aria-label to click the send button.

```
const sendMessage = (message) => {
  console.log('Sending message:', message);
  const liveChatFrame = document.querySelector('iframe.style-scope.ytd-live-chat-frame');
  const chatInputBox = liveChatFrame.contentDocument.querySelector('#input.yt-live-chat-text-input-field-renderer');
  console.log('Chat input box:', chatInputBox);
  chatInputBox.focus();
  chatInputBox.innerText = message;
  chatInputBox.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
  setTimeout(() => {
    const sendButton = liveChatFrame.contentDocument.querySelector('#button.yt-icon-button[aria-label="Send"]');
    console.log('Send button:', sendButton);
    if (sendButton) {
      console.log('Clicking send button');
      try {
        sendButton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', { bubbles: true }));
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error sending message:', error);
      }
    } else {
      console.error('Could not find send button');
    }
  }, 1000);
};
```